# elasticsearch added wildcard fails query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Works as expected:

```
{
  "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "Hofstetten-Grünau"
        }
    }
}
```

an added wildcard at the end delivers no results and I wonder why:

```
{
  "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "Hofstetten-Grünau*"
        }
    }
}
```

how to fix it?

elasticsearch v5.3.2

This delivers results:

```
{
  "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "Hofstetten*"
        }
    }
}
```

I use a single search field. The end user can freely use wildcards as they see fit. A user might type in:

- hofstetten grünau
- +ort:hofstetten-grünau
- +ort:Hofstetten-G*

so using a match query wont work out for me.

I am using Jest (Java Annotations) as Mapping, and using "default" for this field. My index mapping declares nothing special for the field:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "date_detection": false,
            "dynamic_templates": [{
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the mapping you're using? Both queries are working for me (i.e. with and without wildcard)

Comment: I have added the mapping. In v6.2.4 This works: +ort:"Hofstetten-Grünau*" but this doesnt: +ort:"Hofstetten-g*". Since my users might type this they will just file a bug with me

Comment: Note that `Hofstetten*` and `Hofstetten-G*` is not the same, you're looking are using edge-ngram here in order to index prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the wildcard "*" at the end of your query string is causing the query analyzer to interpret the dash between "Hofstetten" and "Grünau" as a logical NOT operator. So you're actually searching for documents that contain Hofstetten but do NOT contain Grünau.

You can verify this by doing the following variations of your search:

```
"query": "Hofstetten-XXXXX" #should not return results
"query": "Hofstetten-XXXXX*" #should return results
```

To fix this I would recommend using a `match` query instead of a `query_string` query:

```
{"query": {"match": { "city": "Hofstetten-Grünau" }}}'
```

(with whatever your appropriate field name is in place of `city`).

Comment: In my use case end users can search over a collection of JSONs in a single search field. And can use wildcard themselves. So I dont think the match query would help me here.